Want to create a mega pivot table from data from a matrix with 11 items, and 4 possible answers
I am trying to analyse data from a survey. In my survey I asked a 'matrix' question, with 11 items, and users could give one of 4 possible answers for each item.
for example:
carrots - i like it | i don't like it | I don't know what this is | n/a
apples  - i like it | i don't like it | I don't know what this is | n/a
bananas - i like it | i don't like it | I don't know what this is | n/a

The data in my table from the people who answered looks like this:



respondent
carrots
bananas




1
i like them
i don't like them


2
i don't like them
etc etc etc



I want a fast/ easy way to create a "mega pivot table" showing me the count for each answer for that item, where the output looks like this:




carrots
bananas




i like them
2
1


i don't like them
5
3



Currently, I get here by doing a separate pivot table for each item and then manually 'knitting' them together with pivot table references, but that takes a long time and I am not sure if there's an easier way to do it.


The non pivot table answer is to use countif() for the data section of the table you are trying to create (leaving your row/column headers intact). The pivot table version will require you to unpivot the data first using power query (can also be done with a formula for newer version so of excel).
